# Nodejs + reactjs + jwt check

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt

First, sorry for my english...
     I'm trying to learn how to built a JWT login and private router in Reactjs... i create simple backend system in nodeJS (register users, list, create JWT token and check jwt) that is working fine ( i think)...
     The problem is in react, when request GET in the API verifyToken( in the file IsAuthenticated), its return true or false, theoretically its working ( first image)... so when i export this file and import in Routes.js this dont return true or false, as you see in image 2, its returning a promise
How i fix this?

again, sorry for my english and thanks for the possible help
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ0Rn.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTfKW.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behaviour. `async` functions return `Promise`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function — a
>   function that is an AsyncFunction object. Asynchronous functions
>   operate in a separate order than the rest of the code via the event
>   loop, returning an **implicit Promise as its result**.

You have to remember once you do any asynchronous operation you cannot go back doing just synchronous operations in that same flow.

You should use your `isAuthenticated()` function in a `useEffect` hook which will change the state.

You can use the function like this:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    isAuthenticated().then(auth=> /*... set the setters hooks or setState ..*/)
});
```

Comment: i dont know how to use this, im new in react, could explain more please

Comment: can u write a example?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal because async function return Promise.

```
async function f() {
  return 1;
}

f().then(res => console.log(res)); // 1
```

You can do like this to get your value

Comment: its worked, but the problem now is in the Routes.js needs to call the isAuthenticated.js every time when go to /home, but i dont know how

Comment: I think you need to add a state like isLoggedIn at app.js, then you have to send as props to all the components you need to check if the user is loggedIn.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your Routes.js `const isAuth = await isAuthenticated();` and then use isAuth instead of isAuthenticated.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use "await" or the callback promise, not both:

```
try {
    const response = await axios.get('/myRequest');
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

or like this:

```
axios.get('/myRequest')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: its returning a promise too